# memcached service stopped unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, memory, clustering

I am working with

- MySQL Cluster 7.2.4
- memcached 1.6

I started memcached service with ndb-caching option:

```
memcached -E /usr/local/mysql/lib/ndb_engine.so -e "connectstring=10.12.200.117:1186;role=ndb-caching;debug=true" -vv -c 20 -u root


mysql> SELECT * FROM memcache_server_roles where role_name='ndb-caching'; 
+-------------+---------+---------+---------------------+ 
| role_name   | role_id | max_tps | update_timestamp    | 
+-------------+---------+---------+---------------------+ 
| ndb-caching | 3       | 100000  | 2012-03-21 17:53:45 | 
+-------------+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

with role id 3

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM key_prefixes where server_role_id=3; 
+----------------+------------+------------+---------+-------------+ 
| server_role_id | key_prefix | cluster_id | policy  | container   | 
+----------------+------------+------------+---------+-------------+ 
| 3              | b:         | 0          | caching | demo_ext    | 
| 3              | t:         | 0          | caching | demo_tabs   | 
| 3              |            | 0          | caching | demo_table  | 
| 3              | d:         | 0          | caching | deepak_new  | 
| 3              | dee:       | 0          | caching | deepak_new1 | 
+----------------+------------+------------+---------+-------------+
```

I just looked into demo_tabs container

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM containers where name='demo_tabs'; 
 +-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+-------+------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
 | name      | db_schema   | db_table        | key_columns | value_columns  | flags | increment_column | cas_column | expire_time_column | large_values_table |
 +-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+-------+------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
 | demo_tabs | ndbmemcache | demo_table_tabs | mkey        | val1,val2,val3 | flags | NULL             | NULL       | expire_time | NULL |
 +-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+-------+------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Now I saw the contents in the ndbmemcache.demo_table_tabs table:

```
select * from ndbmemcache.demo_table_tabs; 

mysql> select * from ndbmemcache.demo_table_tabs; 
+------+--------------+------+------+-------+-------------+ 
| mkey | val1         | val2 | val3 | flags | expire_time | 
+------+--------------+------+------+-------+-------------+ 
| 2    | abcdefghijlk | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL        | 
+------+--------------+------+------+-------+-------------+
```

I expect for the key t:2 values abcdefghijlk, but this value is not there in cache -- it's only in the database.

But still I run get t:2 in telnet the connection closes unexpectedly:

```
[root@cent2 ~]# telnet localhost 11211 
Trying 127.0.0.1... 
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1). 
Escape character is '^]'. 
get t:2 
Connection closed by foreign host. 
[root@cent2 ~]#
```

The memcached service stopped with error message:

```
[root@cent2 ~]#memcached -E /usr/local/mysql/lib/ndb_engine.so -e "connectstring=10.12.200.117:1186;role=ndb-caching;debug=true" -vv -c 20 -u root
 .......................... 
.......................... 
worker.1 schedule():1.0 placed on send queue. 
cl0.conn1.send run_ndb_send_thread():Sent 1.0 
cl0.conn1.poll run_ndb_poll_thread(): ** adding 1.0 to wait group ** 
cl0.conn1.poll run_ndb_poll_thread():Polling 1.0 
cl0.conn1.poll callback_main():Success. 
cl0.conn1.poll worker_finalize_read():1.0 
cl0.conn1.poll --> build_hash_item() 
cl0.conn1.poll build_hash_item():nbytes: 21 ncopied: 16 
Segmentation fault 
[root@cent2 ~]#
```

Why is this service closing unexpectedly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug. Did the set work with multi-column values?

```
SET t:3 0 0 5
a\tb\tc
```

(\t is a tabulator)

Comment: I may be missing something, but could you elaborate on this a bit?  How the `SET` connects to the problem?